# Need UPnP enabled router, that also has port forwarding

Tags: router, upnp

I currently have a 3COM OfficeConnect router, and it seems I cannot get the port forwarding to work, and neither does my Qnap TS-410 seem to be able to recognize the device as UPnP enabled for the cloud service.

I wondered, can anyone tell me if [this](http://home.cisco.com/en-apac/products/routers/E3000) router is UPnP and port forwarding enabled?

If not, what router, a high end one, for wifi, can I get that will let me use these options?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't have to forward ports if you have UPnP enabled on most devices.  It really sounds like you have some other problems that won't be solved by buying a $120 router.

Comment: @Ramhound Unless the particular router is buggy, which happens often or in the case that new router is needed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to meet the requirement you listed.

In general the best way to find out about features of a device you plan to buy is to go to the manufacturer's support site and read the manual for the device.

In your case, you can go [here](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-apac/support/routers/E3000) and find the manual under downloads (the link in the center field doewn't work, but the downloads does). I found the needed info on page 26.